# Some design decisions, Could you give me some advice?

Tags: php, javascript

All my forms submit to a php script by Ajax. the php script just like a controller.

I think this could be more user friendly. if something goes wrong, the user doesn't need to leave the current page.

but i don't see any website do in this way.

he downside is the php runtime have to load twice: one in the posting process. one for showing the result.

Comment: There are plenty of web sites that do it this way, but the potential downside is that if JS is turned off, it won't work any more. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Can't avoid the two server requests: one has to load the form, the second to process the post (whether by AJAX or with page transition). Of course, by AJAX, your server doesn't have to rebuild a while page to respond, only send back the data required for your client-side javascript to process (display ok, error, update affected parts of the page, etc). But as @Pekka alludes, best practice is to deliver a form for standard, "page-transition" post and allow javascript to override the submit behavior. Then everyone, even non-js users - are handled.

Comment: @David. all my forms processed in Ajax way, even the "page-transition" post. in "page-transition" post, the ajax result just a link to the new view.

Comment: @David. why user switch off javascript? i don't see any of my friends do this.

Comment: @lovespring: becuase it's an option.

Comment: Some clients simply don't have js. Even among clients that do have js, like the web browser, many people install extensions - like Firefox's NoScript - to enable/disable js on a per-site basis. Lots of malware functions by employing js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as Pekka commented, there are lots of websites that use ajax technique to submit a form.

If I correctly interpreted your question, usually, I think the best asynch pattern to solve the "form problem", in design terms is this:

=> html form

=> default submit event stopped by JS

=> JS client checks (i.e. email/phone) validation

=> ajax call to a backend script (php, java, ruby, etc) - it loads just once!

=> serverside checks, "echoing" a response

=> ajax call response, handled by JS

Comment: even in the "page-transition" post, do you still post to ajax controller?

Comment: "page-transition" post can be posted to another controller, or in the same ajax controller that can maybe generate a full page response (i.e. if a parameter is passed to it).